# a grounded-channel is still accumulating in lamina

Tags: clojure

I want to use the Lamina library for Clojure, specifically a grounded channel that doesn't return any messages and whose mapped functions (listeners?) are used to transform the message and update UI elements.

My code works fine and does what I expect it to, however when I visualise it, it shows that values are in fact being accumulated:

```
(use 'lamina.core 'lamina.viz)
(def ch (grounded-channel))
(map* inc ch)
(enqueue ch 1 2 3)
(view-graph ch)
```

Those values won't ever be used and cannot be accessed:

```
(read-channel ch)
<< ... >> ;; empty channel
(last* ch)
<< ERROR: :lamina/already-consumed! >>
```

Is this hidden accumulation a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The messages aren't accumulating in the grounded channel, they're accumulating in the channel you created by calling `(map* inc ch)`.  Remember that calling something like `map*` returns a new channel, as described in the "channel operators" section of https://github.com/ztellman/lamina/wiki/Channels-new.  If you want to access the messages that have accumulated in that new channel, you need to call read-channel on the channel returned by `map*`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and thankyou for the library. While I have your attention, is it possible to create a channel where the return values from a mapped function dont accumulate or should I be using a different design altogether?

Comment: I've altered my design a bit so the mapped function now alerts the ui that there are new messages to be read. Whether it decides to read them or not is another thing. This seems more correct.

Comment: You can always call `(ground ch)` on the result from `map*`, if you want.